# delete register DB in laravel 8 with vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Sorry for my question, i´m noob in vueJS

I´m traying to delete user from my DB with vue, i´m working with laravel 8. i have declared my routes how resource and in my controller i have my function destroy.

i have to say that my register it´s eliminated, but laravel returned me 405 error and i don´t understand that i´m doing wrong.

if i do `php artisan route:llist`

i have my route:

```
 DELETE    | admin/users/{user}               | users.destroy                   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController@destroy                               | web
```

and other.

in my controller i have this:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {

        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->delete();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Usuario Eliminado correctamente');
    }
```

if i do axios.get() i can returned my user ok, i think that i´m arrive well to my function.

in my component vue i have `href` that call to my function:

```
<a href="#" @click="deleteUser(data.id)">
                <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
            </a>

deleteUser(id) {
                
                if(confirm("Are you sure to delete this category ?")){
                    let url = '/admin/users/' + id;

                    axios.delete(url)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        //this.$parent.reloadTable();
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                }
            },
```

with `this.$parent.reloadTable();` i want to call my parent component for reload table, although i don´t know very well if my first componet it´s my second component´s parent because i´m doing import in my first component.

My first problem it´s that if i do click in deleteUser delete my user but returned me 405 error and i don´t know that i´m doing wrong.

Thanks for readme al help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem with `axios.post(url, { _method: 'DELETE' })` but now i need call to function from mi other component